# How does ldconfig work?

Tags: ld

I am playing with Ubuntu libraries. I am trying to add some libraries to `/usr/lib/<subdir>/` and to create some proxies for the libraries in `/usr/lib/<subdir>/`.
Note that `/usr/lib/<subdir>/` exists in one of the files in `/etc/ld.so.cond.d/`.
Unfortunately, `ldconf` behaviour seems to be very weird and
non-trivial for me. And that's why:

When I add some library to `/usr/lib/<subdir>/` it is not detected until I add a symbolic link to it from `/usr/lib`. Why?

I found out that often libraries are placed in `/usr/lib/<subdir>/` in a form of triplets:

- `/usr/lib/<subdir>/lib<libname>.so`   - symbolic link to `lib<libname>.so.1`
- `/usr/lib/<subdir>/lib<libname>.so.1` - symbolic link to `lib<libname>.so.<version>`
- `/usr/lib/<subdir>/lib<libname>.so.<version>` - the actual library

Ok. To create a proxy I decided to remove symbolic links and to add my own, say:

- `/usr/lib/<subdir>/lib<libname>abc.so` - symbolic link to `lib<libname>abc.so.1`
- `/usr/lib/<subdir>/lib<libname>abc.so.1` - symbolic link to `lib<libname>.so.<version>`

And then suddenly when I run `sudo ldconfig` to update this stuff it creates `/usr/lib/<subdir>/lib<libname>.so.1` which points to `/usr/lib/<subdir>/lib<libname>abc.so.1.`. Why?

I can't get the logic at all.

Comment: could you post the output of runnig `ldconfig` in verbose mode: `sudo ldconfig -v`?

Comment: @muru The whole output or for some particular part for the directory of interest? It is quite big.

Comment: you can force ldconfig to only run om one directory using the `-n` flag. Post to http://paste.ubuntu.com if the output still is very large.

Comment: Ok, so here it is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7979057/ 
Note the weird 4th line from the end. I did not add this in any way.